# Will I need to replace entire linkage assembly if a part of Wiper system is damaged?

Tags: ford, repair, windshield-wipers, figo

My wipers initially would not stop swiping no matter what I did to turn them off. Than they turned off and would not turn on. The Ford service and repair center told me that my wiring had been eaten by mice and that they will need to replace the entire assembly. This was going to cost me around Rs. 21,000 (260 USD) to get fixed. My car was under warranty, so wrote to Ford. They asked the service center to replace the assembly for free. The service center this time somehow magically fixed it without having to replace the assembly. The system broke down again after around a year. The service center in-charge again insisted on replacing the assembly. However, one of the mechanics quietly told me that the system can actually be fixed in Rs 1,600 (20 USD). Now my car is out of warranty and I will have to pay for the repair out of pocket. So, any idea who is telling the truth and what might actually be wrong with my front wiper system. The car is 2017-18 Ford Figo Aspire (Sold in India)

Comment: What are the new symptoms?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My suggestion is, if the mechanic told you it can be repaired for cheap, ask him if he'd do the work on the side for you.

Comment: The wipers have stopped functioning completely. The washer fluid system still works just fine. The service center in-charge removed a small black piece from the wiper system and put it in my glove box when I took my car for repair this time. Apparently it has to be the thing which has been broken/disconnected. I don't understand what it is. Could it be the motor relay or the switch?